# Firebase Invalid Custom Token

Tags: php, firebase, token, firebase-authentication

I'm using custom token auth on Firebase. I tried to generate token as the documentation said. But when I try to login in client side with (`loginWithCustomToken(token)`) method it gives an error below

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN"
 }
}
```

I generate token with this code block as described in Firebase documentation

```
$service_account_email = "USED_FROM_JSON_FILE"; //
$private_key = "USED_FROM_JSON_FILE";

function create_custom_token($uid, $is_premium_account) {
  global $service_account_email, $private_key;

  $now_seconds = time();
  $payload = array(
    "iss" => $service_account_email,
    "sub" => $service_account_email,
    "aud" => "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit",
    "iat" => $now_seconds,
    "exp" => $now_seconds+(60*60),  // Maximum expiration time is one hour
    "uid" => $uid,
    "claims" => array(
      "premium_account" => $is_premium_account
    )
  );
  return JWT::encode($payload, $private_key, "RS256");
}
```

Comment: Your server might have timezone other than `UTC`. Please provide UTC timestamp to your payload.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this updating the time of my PC.
The date and time was wrong and when i updated it, the error was solved